# navigate to a new page or window from a page in a desktop WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

How can I navigate to a new page or `Window` from a page in a desktop WPF application. I have tried the following to call the windows page, but I get the error:

> Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual

```
private void btCode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CodeView window = new CodeView(cbRe.Text, txtID.Text);
    this.Content = window;
}
```

When I alter code to call a new page I get a similar error saying page must be called from a `Window`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page opening a Window

```
myWindow w = new myWindow();
         w.Show();
```

Navigating to a new page

```
myPage p = new myPage();
       myFrameInCurrentWindow.Navigate(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the navigation features of wpf: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the `Window`element must be the root element - it cannot be a child of another control. You can *open* a window from another control, but you cannot make a window the content of another control.